# WinForms RichTextBox selection issue if there is hidden text

Tags: c#, winforms, selection, richtextbox, hidden

I have a selection problem with RichTextBox control. If the control contains hidden text, the selection behaves strangely.

- If I do a selection with the mouse, sometimes the bug is present, sometimes not. Especially if I select more lines the bug seems to disappear.
- But the bug is very annoying if the user tries to select the text with the **keyboard**.

The issue is the following: Let's say my control has this text:

> There is the little upgraded control that hopefully will make a
>   differnce when it is hidden text the reason

Then let's say we hide words `upgraded, hopefully, hidden` by applying proper RTF tags:

```
@"{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang2057{\fonttbl{\f0\fni‌​l\fcharset0 Microsoft Sans Serif;}} \viewkind4\uc1\pard\f0\fs17 There is the little \v upgraded \v0 control that \v hopefully \v0 will make a differnce when it is \v hidden \v0 text the reason\par}";
```

It all looks good, but when the user tries to select the text using the keyboard, selection seems to reset every time a hidden word is reached.

It is crucial for my control to contain that hidden text (some important id's from my objects that are forming the content inside the control are stored as hidden text at special positions, and I can't/don't want to change that).

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue with clean new project? I mean can you create a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for this issue?

Comment: Yes, it seems to be easy reproducible. I don't think it is a bug in my code, but rather a behavior of the rich textbox control, or bug inside the control itself. [here you can find sample project with the bug](https://www.dropbox.com/s/sef62c2c2kt2ds2/rtbTest.zip?dl=0)

Just click at the beggining of the text (inside the first textbox) it already contains hidden content, hold shift and press left arrow as you would normally select text using the keyboard.
The selection will reset when it reach hidden word

Comment: Can you provide a MCVE? I mean at least the RTF used. Just check that you can truly reproduce it with clean project with that RTF.

Comment: I wasn't sure how to post a link here :), so I had to edit my previous comment. Please find the test project on the link in my previous comment. 

Thank you for trying to help.

Comment: You'd better put the sample RTF in the question itself. Something like `richTextBox.Rtf = @"{\rtf1\ansi{\fonttbl\f0\fswiss Helvetica;}\f0\pard
This is some {\b bold} text.\par
}"` so one can just create new WinForms project with `richTextBox` and reproduce the issue.

Comment: Here you can find also sample rtf @"{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang2057{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Microsoft Sans Serif;}} \viewkind4\uc1\pard\f0\fs17 There is the little \v upgraded \v0 control that \v hopefully \v0 will make a differnce when it is \v hidden \v0 text the reason\par}";

but also note that on the link you can download the entire project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using the following `Form`, where `richTextBox` is the `RichTextBox` in question and `RichTextBox_SelectionChanged` is the [SelectionChanged event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.selectionchanged(v=vs.110).aspx) handler that we will try to use to fix our issue.

```
public MainForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    this.richTextBox.Rtf =
        @"{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang2057{\fonttbl{\f0\fni‌​l\fcharset0 Microsoft Sans Serif;}}\viewkind4\uc1\pard\f0\fs17 My \v upgraded \v0 control that \v hopefully \v0 will make it\par}";            
    this.richTextBox.SelectionChanged += RichTextBox_SelectionChanged;
}
```

Basically, the idea is simple - use `SelectionChanged` handler to properly [Select](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.select(v=vs.110).aspx) hidden data alongside the previous selection.

For that we will have to store the previous selection data:

```
private class SelectionData
{
    public static SelectionData FromStartAndEnd(
        Int32 start,
        Int32 end)
    {
        return new SelectionData(
            start: start,
            length: end - start);
    }

    public SelectionData(TextBoxBase tb)
        : this(
            start: tb.SelectionStart,
            length: tb.SelectionLength)
    {            }

    public SelectionData(Int32 start, Int32 length)
    {
        this.Start = start;
        this.Length = length;
    }

    public readonly Int32 Start, Length;
    public Int32 End
    {
        get
        {
            return this.Start + this.Length;
        }
    }
}
```

in some field:

```
private SelectionData _previousSelection;
```

And update/fix selection inside the `SelectionChanged` hanlder

```
private void RichTextBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var newSelection = new SelectionData(this.richTextBox);
    this.SelfUpdateSelection(newSelection);
}
```

`SelfUpdateSelection` method would be something like:

```
private Boolean _isSelectionSelfUpdating = false;

private void SelfUpdateSelection(SelectionData newSelection)
{
    if (!this.IsKeyBoardSelection())
    {
        // Or it will use previous selection when we don't need it.
        this._previousSelection = null; 
        return;
    }
    if (this._isSelectionSelfUpdating)
        return;

    this._isSelectionSelfUpdating = true;
    try
    {
        var fixedSelection = this.FixSelection(newSelection);
        this.richTextBox.Select(
            start: fixedSelection.Start,
            length: fixedSelection.Length);
        this._previousSelection = fixedSelection;
    }
    finally
    {
        this._isSelectionSelfUpdating = false;
    }
}
```

`IsKeyBoardSelection` for simplicity can be something like the following, though properly detecting selection change source will be more difficult:

```
private bool IsKeyBoardSelection()
{
    // It may not be true, but usually close enough.
    return Control.ModifierKeys.HasFlag(Keys.Shift);
}
```

`FixSelection` method should compare whether `newSelection` can be a `this._previousSelection` and create a new `SelectionData` that will contain both `newSelection`, `this._previousSelection` and the hidden data between them.

You can use something like this:

```
private SelectionData FixSelection(SelectionData newSelection)
{
    if (this._previousSelection == null)
        return newSelection;

    var start = Math.Min(
        newSelection.Start,
        this._previousSelection.Start);
    var end = Math.Max(
        newSelection.End,
        this._previousSelection.End);
    return SelectionData.FromStartAndEnd(
        start: start,
        end: end);
}
```

but it:

- Will work only with **forward(right arrow) selection** - can be fixed by adding some additional logic to `FixSelection`.
- Will also require a bit of **additional `this._previousSelection` handling** (like resetting it on FocusLost event) - there are some edge cases, but still nothing impossible.

  ```
  public MainForm()
  {
      ...
      this.richTextBox.LostFocus += RichTextBox_LostFocus;
  }

  private void RichTextBox_LostFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      this._previousSelection = null;
  }
  ```

**P.S.:** For simplicity I have implemented everything inside the form with fields and form-level handlers, but with some effort it could be made into something reusable (at worst derived `RichTextBox`, at best some external component that will provide such handling for `RichTextBox`).

Comment: Thank you for your response and sorry for marking it as resolved after a long time. It is the right answer to my question, but unfortunately, it wasn't an answer to our problem. We had to take another direction because of a slight change in the riles we had. Keeping our data hidden in the text was not possible nor allowed with the new requirements. 

Anyway, it was an interesting problem to play with and thank you for all your assistance.